# How to Condense & Nest a (CSV) Payload in Dataweave 2.0?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I have a CSV payload TV Programs & Episodes that I want to Transform (Nest & Condense) to a JSON, with the following conditions:

- Merge consecutive Program Lines (that are not followed by an Episode Line), so that it becomes 1 Program with the Start Date of the 1st Instance and the Summation of the Duration.
- Episode Lines after a Program Line are Nested under the Program

**INPUT**

```js
Channel|Name|Start|Duration|Type
ACME|Broke Girls|2018-02-01T00:00:00|600|Program
ACME|Broke Girls|2018-02-01T00:10:00|3000|Program
ACME|S03_8|2018-02-01T00:13:05|120|Episode
ACME|S03_9|2018-02-01T00:29:10|120|Episode
ACME|S04_1|2018-02-01T00:44:12|120|Episode
ACME|Lost In Translation|2018-02-01T02:01:00|1800|Program
ACME|Lost In Translation|2018-02-01T02:30:00|1800|Program
ACME|The Demolition Man|2018-02-01T03:00:00|1800|Program
ACME|The Demolition Man|2018-02-01T03:30:00|1800|Program
ACME|The Demolition Man|2018-02-01T04:00:00|1800|Program
ACME|The Demolition Man|2018-02-01T04:30:00|1800|Program
ACME|Photon|2018-02-01T05:00:00|1800|Program
ACME|Photon|2018-02-01T05:30:00|1800|Program
ACME|Miles & Smiles|2018-02-01T06:00:00|3600|Program
ACME|S015_1|2018-02-01T06:13:53|120|Episode
ACME|S015_2|2018-02-01T06:29:22|120|Episode
ACME|S015_3|2018-02-01T06:46:28|120|Episode
ACME|Ice Age|2018-02-01T07:00:00|300|Program
ACME|Ice Age|2018-02-01T07:05:00|600|Program
ACME|Ice Age|2018-02-01T07:15:00|2700|Program
ACME|S01_4|2018-02-01T07:17:17|120|Episode
ACME|S01_5|2018-02-01T07:32:11|120|Episode
ACME|S01_6|2018-02-01T07:47:20|120|Episode
ACME|My Girl Friday|2018-02-01T08:00:00|3600|Program
ACME|S05_7|2018-02-01T08:17:28|120|Episode
ACME|S05_8|2018-02-01T08:31:59|120|Episode
ACME|S05_9|2018-02-01T08:44:42|120|Episode
ACME|Pirate Bay|2018-02-01T09:00:00|3600|Program
ACME|S01_1|2018-02-01T09:33:12|120|Episode
ACME|S01_2|2018-02-01T09:46:19|120|Episode
ACME|Broke Girls|2018-02-01T10:00:00|1200|Program
ACME|S05_3|2018-02-01T10:13:05|120|Episode
ACME|S05_4|2018-02-01T10:29:10|120|Episode
```

**OUTPUT**

```js
{
  "programs": [
    {
      "StartTime": "2018-02-01T00:00:00",
      "Duration": 3600,
      "Name": "Broke Girls",
      "episode": [
        {
          "name": "S03_8",
          "startDateTime": "2018-02-01T00:13:05",
          "duration": 120
        },
        {
          "name": "S03_9",
          "startDateTime": "2018-02-01T00:29:10",
          "duration": 120
        },
        {
          "name": "S04_1",
          "startDateTime": "2018-02-01T00:44:12",
          "duration": 120
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "StartTime": "2018-02-01T06:00:00",
      "Duration": 3600,
      "Name": "Miles & Smiles",
      "episode": [
        {
          "name": "S015_1",
          "startDateTime": "2018-02-01T06:13:53",
          "duration": 120
        },
        {
          "name": "S015_2",
          "startDateTime": "2018-02-01T06:29:22",
          "duration": 120
        },
        {
          "name": "S015_3",
          "startDateTime": "2018-02-01T06:46:28",
          "duration": 120
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "StartTime": "2018-02-01T07:00:00",
      "Duration": 3600,
      "Name": "Ice Age",
      "episode": [
        {
          "name": "S01_4",
          "startDateTime": "2018-02-01T07:17:17",
          "duration": 120
        },
        {
          "name": "S01_5",
          "startDateTime": "2018-02-01T07:32:11",
          "duration": 120
        },
        {
          "name": "S01_6",
          "startDateTime": "2018-02-01T07:47:20",
          "duration": 120
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "StartTime": "2018-02-01T08:00:00",
      "Duration": 3600,
      "Name": "My Girl Friday",
      "episode": [
        {
          "name": "S05_7",
          "startDateTime": "2018-02-01T08:17:28",
          "duration": 120
        },
        {
          "name": "S05_8",
          "startDateTime": "2018-02-01T08:31:59",
          "duration": 120
        },
        {
          "name": "S05_9",
          "startDateTime": "2018-02-01T08:44:42",
          "duration": 120
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "StartTime": "2018-02-01T09:00:00",
      "Duration": 3600,
      "Name": "Pirate Bay",
      "episode": [
        {
          "name": "S01_1",
          "startDateTime": "2018-02-01T09:33:12",
          "duration": 120
        },
        {
          "name": "S01_2",
          "startDateTime": "2018-02-01T09:46:19",
          "duration": 120
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "StartTime": "2018-02-01T10:00:00",
      "Duration": 1200,
      "Name": "Broke Girls",
      "episode": [
        {
          "name": "S05_3",
          "startDateTime": "2018-02-01T10:13:05",
          "duration": 120
        },
        {
          "name": "S05_4",
          "startDateTime": "2018-02-01T10:29:10",
          "duration": 120
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure DataWeave can support this data format. It is more a variable leng file structure with multi level records with a record type identifier at the end (Type). The structure doesn't make much sense. You should explain how it is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try, comments are embedded:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/dw
var data = readUrl("classpath://data.csv","application/csv",{separator:"|"})
var firstProgram = data[0].Name
---
// Identify the programs by adding a field
(data reduce (e,acc={l: firstProgram, c:0, d: []}) -> do {
    var next = acc.l != e.Name and e.Type == "Program" 
    var counter = if (next) acc.c+1 else acc.c
    ---
    {
        l: if (next) e.Name else acc.l,
        c: counter,
        d: acc.d + {(e), pc: counter}
    }
}).d 
// group by the identifier of individual programs
groupBy $.pc
// Get just the programs throw away the program identifiers 
pluck $
// Throw away the programs with no episodes
filter ($.*Type contains "Episode")
// Iterate over the programs
map do {
    // sum the program duration
    var d = $ dw::core::Arrays::sumBy (e) -> if (e.Type == "Program") e.Duration else 0
    // Get the episodes and do a little cleanup
    var es = $ map $-"pc" filter ($.Type == "Episode")
    ---
    // Form the desired structure
    {
        ($[0] - "pc" - "Duration"),
        Duration: d,
        Episode: es 
    }
}
```

**NOTE1**: I stored the contents in a file and read it using `readUrl`, you need to adjust to accommodate from where you get your data from.

**NOTE2**: Maybe you need to rethink your inputs, organize them better, if possible.

**NOTE3**: Studio will show errors (at least Studio 7.5.1 does).  They are false positives, the code runs

**NOTE4**: Lots of steps because of the non-trivial input.  Potentialy the code could be optimized but I did spend enough time on it--I 'll let you deal with the optimization or somebody else from the community can help.

Comment: Thanks, George.
That's as closest as 1 can ask from a Community ;)
I tried a different method, had worse performance; and is too ugly and embarrassing to show in public :)